# Interested in Grabbing XBOX Friend's List

Tags: php, windows, authentication, live, xbox

I would like to get the list of XBOX friends for a certain gamercard (http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/Friends.aspx) and display it in a widget for my site.

I know that there are alot of iPhone apps that do just that, but I would like to do it on the web, without an iPhone.

Does anyone know of a PHP class to either login via cURL to live.com so that I can scrape the details or if there is a RSS feed somewhere that I can use.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/10253/53817.aspx

Comment: @Jed:  that post isn't entirely accurate.  cf. my answer about XCDP below.

Comment: Please read and rate my comment here for information on my API - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549945/1247344

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft frowns on screen scraping of the Xbox.com website.  If you screen scrape a lot of data, you're likely to get your IP(s) blocked (though, I don't know that it's expressly forbidden by the terms of service or how actively they block IP addresses; it's just that they *could*).

There *is* a community XML API for most of the Xbox.com gamer data, but it is not available to the general public.  In order to access the API, you need to become a member of the Xbox Community Developer Program (XCDP).  Membership is free, but I don't know that the program is accepting new members right now, and I don't know that there is a public website for the program.

Comment: Your first paragraph is most likely not true. I am scrapping some data from xbox.com and so far so good (not directly from the profile though).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no open API nor you can scrap the data easily as logging in into live is real beach - it does some data manipulations with javascript before submitting the form. So if you want to login you need to either crack that js algorithm or run your own js engine, none of which is easy. I tried doing that some time ago and gave up.