# Can I query my / my friends games on Xbox Live?

Tags: c#, .net, live, xbox360

Is there any way for me to query via C# on a web or desktop application all my games on Xbox Live ?

Comment: Why the downvote ? Please explain, it could help me ask better questions.

Comment: That link is now dead... Please read and rate my comment here for information on my Unofficial Xbox LIVE API - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9549945/1247344

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an unofficial Xbox Live API [here](http://community.xboxleaders.com/xbox-live-api/xbox-live-gamercard-api-48.0.html)

You can view details such as:

- Online status
- Avatars
- Gamerscore
- Bio
- Recent games played

Unfortunately, it seems  you can't view all games currently, but keep an eye out on the site as it seems to be under active development (as of Dec 2011)

Comment: So, as I can see, there is no official MS API do integrate with live, is that correct ? The link suggests that this alternative API is currently scraping content from the official site, right ?

Comment: I was just reading the linked site and it seems this is correct.  Also, it seems that the list of games is not currently available.